# Internet stops working suddenly on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, internet

While surfing the internet or watching youtube videos my internet just suddenly stop working on my pc. It shows that I am connected to the internet but I am not able to browse it. Even ping stops working in the terminal. But if I manually turn off the wifi and then turn it back on and then connect to the wifi, then it starts working again. I don't know what the issue is here. I have installed the macOS theme so is this issue because of that?
My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Is this an issue that happened after installing Ubuntu , or occurred after Ubuntu was running well for a while? If the latter, did you perform any updates or make any other hardware/software changes to your machine? Are there any other PCs that do have Internet access, or is this the only machine that's having the problem? What is "the MacOS sking?" Thanks

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @richbl I installed Ubuntu just 2-3 days back so its a new issue, and the internet is working on other devices, the problem happens on ubuntu only. And sorry about the typo, it had to be "macos skin", or that I installed macos theme on my ubuntu.

Comment: @waltinator What should I look for specifically in the logs or should I paste it here?